# vscode not autocompleting certain Python methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, intellisense

This issue appears for some Modules I don't remember which other one I had issues with yesterday but for now the **re** module seems to have issues auto completing. Tried the same code with pycharm and had no issues. Not sure why.

vscode example.

[image]

Pycharm example.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the python exetnsion installed and if so what version

Comment: I do, its v2020.12.424452561.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

You can Install [pylance language server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) for language support after reinstalling vscode

**OR**

In vs code open command palette `Ctrl+Shift+p`

There select `Python:Select Interpreter` from the command pallete
[image: Selecting python interpreter from the comman pallete]

Close your vs code and then try.

Comment: I plan on adding helpful pictures tommorow but dont have time now

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had already selected my interpreter to be my venv folder Python 3.8.6 and still had issue. I tried the second suggestion you suggested and I got Command 'Python: Build Workspace Symbols' resulted in an error (command'python.buildWorkspaceSymbols' not found)

Comment: Although rebuilding the workspace symbols doesn't work, I reinstalled vscode from scratch and added pylance language server as suggested by vscode itself. It seems to have done the trick as now the methods show for re.

Comment: The workspace symbols is a problem I couldnt find a solution to so I updated my answer to incorporate pylance

Comment: Marked as answer hopefully this will help others. Thanks.